# Listar resultado do Banco em checkbox com AJAX e JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5, ajax

Eu tenho uma função que busca no banco uma lista de entidade e mostra no select. No entanto, eu preciso que essa mesma lista seja mostrada em checkbox onde o usuário poderá marcar mais de uma opção.
Como mostrar essa lista de resultados no < input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id"">?
Como pegar no submit os valores marcados?

JS atual monta a lista em um < Select >, preciso substituir para check:

```
 function CarregaEntrada() {
         $.ajax({
             url: "/Qualidade/Entidade/CarregaEntidade",
                //data: { representante: representante },
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#entrada").empty();
                    $("#entrada").append('<option value="0" disabled selected hidden>Selecione...</option>');

                    $.each(data, function (i, element) {
                        $("#entrada").append('<option value=' + element.Id + '>' + element.Descricao + '</option>');
                    });

                }
            });
        }

    });
```

html atual- (preciso substituir o select por check)

```
  <div class="col-md-10">
       <select class="form-control select2" id="entrada" name="entrada"></select>
      </div>
```

Comment: coloca um id na div para facilitar, por exemplo "divEntradas" e muda o comando dentro do `each` por: `$('#divEntradas').append('<input type="checkbox" name="entrada" id="' + element.Id +'"  />' + element.Descricao);`, agora para adicionar o `checked` você precisa de alguma propriedade no retorno dizendo se está selecionado.

Comment: opa.. Vou tentar sua sugestão

Comment: @RicardoPontual Deu certo. Obrigada.. Agora poderia me ajudar me orientando de  como pegar os itens selecionados no envio do formulário? - coloque na resposta e que eu marco como a certa.

Comment: Sim, como é o dado que você precisa passar por ajax? um array de números, uma string..?

Comment: @RicardoPontual vou passar por AJAX o formulario e a cada item selecionado, será um insert em uma tabela onde conterá o ID do formulario e o ID da Entidade (1 :N ). O mesmo formulário poderá ter varias entidades.

Comment: postei como uma resposta pra ficar mais fácil de visualizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então para pegar o resultado da consulta `Ajax` e gerar os *checkboxes*:

```
$.each(data, function (i, element) {
    $('#divEntradas').append('<input type="checkbox" name="entrada" id="' + element.Id +'" />' + element.Descricao);
});
```

Para submeter o form que tem os checkboxes, pode usar o `serialize` do `JQuery` para ajudar:

```
var form = $('#id_do_form');

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: form.attr('action'),
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function(resposta) {
     console.log(resposta);
  }
});
```

Aqui aproveitei como url a própria *action* do form, mas poderia substituir por outra url específica.

Comment: Na verdade o envio do form é tranquilo. A dúvida é como pegar os valores marcados no check ja que é um array com o mesmo name

Comment: Entendi, isso no javascript ou no asp.net?

Comment: asp.net mvc....

Comment: Você pode colocar no seu método para receber um `(FormCollection form)`. Para ler os checkboxes, pode acessar a coleção por nome: `var checkboxes = form["entrada"]`